# Color Profile and ColorSpace mismatch using RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, mismatch

In a ruby on rails enviornment, Im trying to convert a jpeg image from RGB to CMYK and back to RGB to create a pdf, and i want to add icc profiles (from Adobe) when converting (I am using Magick with the Rmagick gem). However, I keep getting this error "ColorSpace ColorProfile Mismatch", which is pretty self explanatory. What i don't understand is this:

```
2.0.0p195 :083 >   image.colorspace
=> RGBColorspace=1 
2.0.0p195 :084 > image.add_profile("lib/assets/AdobeRGB1998.icc")
Magick::ImageMagickError: ColorspaceColorProfileMismatch `icc' @error/profile.c/ProfileImage/582
```

How is there a mismatch when the colorspace matches the profile?

Answer (score 0):

"/lib/assets/AdobeRGB1998.icc", not "lib/assets/AdobeRGB1998.icc". Typos....